# $J(X)$ and exotic spheres.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, differential-topology

I read that we can realize exotic sphere as the coker of $J$-homomorphism. SO we can consider the exotic sphere $S^7$ realized using an identificantion of $B^4 \times S^3$ (where I donote the four dimentional ball). How can I realize this exotic sphere as coker of $J$-homomorphism? In particular, can I realize exotic spheres as coker of complex $J$-homomorphism
$$ J:\pi_r(U(n)) \to \pi_{r+q}(S^q) ?$$

Answer (score 4):

I don't know where you read this, but it is not quite true. What *is* true is that we have an exact sequence
$$0 \longrightarrow \Theta_{n}/bP_{n+1} \longrightarrow \mathrm{coker}(J_n) \stackrel{K_n}{\longrightarrow} C_n \longrightarrow 0.$$
Here we have that

- $\Theta_n$ is the group of homotopy $n$-spheres.
- $bP_{n+1}$ is the subgroup of $\Theta_n$ consisting of homotopy $n$-spheres that bound a parallelizable $(n+1)$-manifold.
- $K_n$ is the Kervaire invariant.
- $C_n$ is a group that depends on $n$:
  $$C_n = \begin{cases} 0, & n \not\equiv 2 \pmod 4, \\ \Bbb Z/2 \,\text{ or }\, 0, & n \equiv 2 \pmod 4. \end{cases}$$

We have that $C_n = \Bbb Z/2$ for precisely those $n$ for which there exists an $n$-manifold of Kervaire invariant $1$. Finding which $n$ satisfy this property was a huge open problem in algebraic topology which was settled in 2009 for all cases except $n = 126$. It turns out that $C_n = \Bbb Z/2$ for $n = 6$, $14$, $30$, $62$, and possibly $n = 126$. Hence we have the following:

> **Theorem.** For $n = 6$, $14$, $30$, or $62$, we have an exact sequence
>   $$0 \longrightarrow \Theta_{n}/bP_{n+1} \longrightarrow \mathrm{coker}(J_n) \stackrel{K_n}{\longrightarrow} \Bbb Z/2 \longrightarrow 0. \tag{$\ast$}$$
>   For $n \neq 6$, $14$, $30$, $62$, or $126$, we have an isomorphism
>   $$\Theta_n/bP_{n+1} \cong \mathrm{coker}(J_n). \tag{$\ast\ast$}$$
>   For $n = 126$, one of $(\ast)$ or $(\ast\ast)$ holds.

Comment: I read it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-homomorphism in the section: Appplication.

Comment: That article just says $\mathrm{coker}(J_n)$ _appears_ in (the study of) exotic spheres, _i.e._ the cokernel of the $J$-homomorphism and exotic spheres are _somehow_ related. The precise relationship they are talking about is what I said in my answer.